# UWP Drag and Drop between Multiple ListViews

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm having some trouble with Drag and Drop between different ListViews. I have a GridView that contains multiple ListView all from the same ObservableCollection. Basically, I want to be able to drag items from one ListView into another Listview but within the same GridView.

Below is the ListView Which is part of the DataTemplate for the GridView. The ListView is Bound to a ObservableCollection of string. Which is a Property or the ObservableCollection the  GridView is bound too.

```
<ListView Name="ListingView"  Height="200"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True"
                      DragItemsStarting="ListView_DragItemsStarting"
                      DragOver="ListView_DragOver"
                      CanReorderItems="True"
                      DragItemsCompleted="ListView_DragItemsCompleted"
                      Drop="ListView_Drop" ItemsSource="{Binding Listing}" 
                      />
```

And here is the Code Behind for the ListView

```
    private void ListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {

        var item = string.Join(",", e.Items.Cast<string>());

        e.Data.SetText(item);
        e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;



    }

    private void ListView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
        {


            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;


        }
    }

    private async void ListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
        {
            var item = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();

            var destinationListView = sender as ListView;
            var listViewItemsSource = destinationListView?.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>;

            if (listViewItemsSource != null)
            {


                listViewItemsSource.Add(item);



            }


        }
    }

    private void ListView_DragItemsCompleted(ListViewBase sender, DragItemsCompletedEventArgs args)
    {

        var item = string.Join(",", args.Items.Cast<string>());

        var destinationListView = sender as ListView;
        var listViewItemsSource = destinationListView?.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>;



        listViewItemsSource.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

The Problem I have is finding a way to stop a ListView from becoming completely empty if I drag all the items out of the a ListView. Once the ListView becomes empty I can't go back and drag something into it.

The Second problem is when I drag an item and then let go of it in the same ListView it was dragged from then it deletes and does no re-add  the item. 
I think I need to add an If statement to the DragItemCompleted method to see If the source is the same as the target before removing the item.

**Edit I seem to have fixed" the second problem by removing the CanReorderItemsProperty from the listView. I'm not sure why but it seems to have fixed up that issue.  But now i can't reorder the lists :(**

Comment: Solution for prob1:- In ListView_DragItemsStarting check the listview items count. if count is one dont do anything

Comment: You should not remove CanReorderItemsProperty . If True, items in the view can be reordered through user interaction; otherwise, false. The default is false.

Comment: Thanks fixed problem one, and almost found a solution to problem 2

Answer (score 0):

Look into this windows sample program https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop/cs